# bash variable evaluating with quote for special character

Tags: bash, expression, special-characters, eval

Below is a simple bash script to test for few password in rar file.
When the password contains special character (!), then I see that the option (-p) is completely parsed with quote (').

```
#!/bin/bash -x

pwd=`echo Sei{0..9}{0..9}b{0..9}axq!zx`
#pwd=Sei03b4axq!zx
file="test.rar"
for eachpwd in $pwd
do
    eval unrar x "$file" -p"$eachpwd" id 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null
    c=$?
    if [ $c = 0 ]
        then echo "Success"
        exit
    fi
    echo $eachpwd $c
done
```

Output

```
+ for eachpwd in '$pwd'
+ eval unrar x test.rar '-pSei49b4axq!zx' id
+ c=10
+ '[' 10 = 0 ']'
+ echo 'Sei49b4axq!zx' 10
```

Question
How do I code such that, the during eval I do not get `unrar x test.rar '-pSei49b4axq!zx' id` instead get `unrar x test.rar -pSei49b4axq!zx id` as evaluated expression

**Update 1**
Tried the below code, but still the quote(!) over the -p option refuses to budge.

```
passwords=( Sei{0..9}{0..9}b{0..9}axq!zx )
file=test.rar

for password in "${passwords[@]}"; do
    if unrar x "$file" -p"$password" id 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null; then
        echo "Success"
        exit
    else
        echo $password failed.
    fi
done
```

Result

```
   + for password in '"${passwords[@]}"'
    + unrar x test.rar '-pSei21b0axq!zx' id
    + echo 'Sei21b0axq!zx' failed.
    Sei21b0axq!zx failed.
    + for password in '"${passwords[@]}"'
    + unrar x test.rar '-pSei21b1axq!zx' id
```

Please note that I am using bash shell for the execution.

Comment: Why are you using `eval`?

Comment: `unrar x "$file" -p"$eachpwd" id 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null` doesn't need to be `eval`'d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of possible explanations for what is happening, none of which are worth exploring because you don't need to use `eval`. Also, it's better to use an array to hold your passwords, or just put the brace expression directly in the `for` loop, rather than creating a single string.

```
# I use single quotes on the very small chance history expansion
# is enabled, to protect the !. You almost certainly can drop them.
passwords=( Sei{0..9}{0..9}b{0..9}'axq!zx' )

for password in "${passwords[@]}"; do
    if unrar x "$file" -p "$eachpwd" id 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null; then
        echo "Success"
        exit
    fi
done
```

Comment: I tried to use your code, but the quotes over -p option evidently from (!) refuses to go. I have updated my question with results for easy reference.

Comment: One thing I forgot: add a space between `-p` and the password, or `unrar` will treat the entire string as a group of single-characters options `-p`, `-S`, `-e`, etc.

Comment: Also, while debugging, remove the `2>/dev/null` so you can see any error messages `unrar` might be throwing.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is simply the regular disambiguation of its output that `set -x` causes Bash to perform.  (Notice how the password is also single quoted in the `echo` output from `set -x`.) The problem, if there is one, is not with the single quotes in the debug output.

Generally, you should quote more, not less. Use double quotes around your variables unless you specifically require Bash to perform wildcard expansion and word splitting on the value.

```
echo "$password failed"
```

Also, the `echo` in backticks is [useless](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#echo). The commented-out assignment is better, but really; use single quotes to make sure you get a literal string and nothing else.

```
pwd='Sei49b4axq!zx'
```

And, as others have already pointed out, the `eval` is not only superfluous, but potentially the reason you are having issues (if indeed you are; your question doesn't actually explain what problem you are attempting to solve!)